# Using http_basic_authenticate_with based on a conditional and instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to password protect one view in my Rails app. I've figured out that I can use `http_basic_authenticate_with` which works well, however I'd like to add some more sophistication.

*Note: I'm already using Devise for authentication for users but this is for a user sharing a view to an external person who won't have an account.*

A user can now add a simple password to the Captable which I want other external guests to have to enter to view the `captables/private_captable_view` view. If there is no password set and the user has a valid `access_token`, then the user can view the `captables/private_captable_view` anyway (this works already).

What I'm trying to achieve is that the `http_basic_authenticate_with` only runs if:

- `has_valid_access_token?` returns true (currently works)
- the Captable has a password set (i.e. `@captable.password.empty?`)
- I'd like to be able to set the necessary password for the http authenticate method to `@captable.password?`
- that the guest only has to enter the password, not a username but I'm unsure if this is possible.
- If the guest enters the right password we render the `captables/private_captable_view`

Here's a snapshot from my controller.

```
class CaptablesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_company, unless: -> { request.xhr? }
    before_action :set_captable, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy], unless: -> { request.xhr? }
    before_action :authenticate_user!, unless: :has_valid_access_token?, only: [:show]
    http_basic_authenticate_with name: "secret", password: "secret", if: :has_valid_access_token?, only: [:show]

    def index
      @captables = @company.captables
    end

    def show
      @captable = Captable.find(params[:id])

      if has_valid_access_token?
        if !@captable.password.empty?
            # TODO use a http basic authenticate here to verify the user enters the password matching @captable.password if so render the private view.
        else
            render 'captables/private_captable_view'
        end
      end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're setting a captable before authentication, you can use `@captable` in `http_basic_authenticate_with`. Also you need to create a separate private method to check all your conditions:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, unless: :able_to_see?, only: [:show]
http_basic_authenticate_with name: "secret", password: @captable.password, if: :able_to_see?, only: [:show]

def show
  # Note, @captable is already set in before_action.
  # IMHO, it's better to follow conventions and name the view `show`, 
  # in this case just leave the action empty
  render 'captables/private_captable_view'
end

private

def able_to_see?
  has_valid_access_token? && @captable.password.present?
end
```

> that the guest only has to enter the password, not a username but I'm
>   unsure if this is possible

Unfortunately, this is impossible

Comment: Thank you! This solution looks good. I'll implement a "name" attribute as well so the guest must use both to authenticate.

Comment: @JP89, happy to help you :)